# How to take an animation off an object thats parent to another

Tags: animation, game-engine

so basically I have a camera and an object (health bar) parent to it. The camera has animations within its movements, both the camera and health bar are parent so they stay by each other of course. But I want only the camera to work with the animations and the health bar to sit still.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup. What happens when you parent the healthbar to the object it belongs to?

Comment: So the Camera and the health bar are parent, the Camera has animations on it when you sprint or move or jump. The health bar copies these animations, I don't want it to be copying these animations, I want it to just stick in the camera and not move when the user is moving.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to have the heath bar as the child of the camera, while only following the general motion of the camera (Not small movements caused by animations). Sounds like you want constraints not a parenting.

Comment: @Aoradon Exactly what I want, I don't know how to work this though so if you could please explain I'd be grateful. :D

Comment: @Marcel Torch - I think you may be looking for the "Track To" constraint. You can remove the "Parent" by pressing Alt + "P" with your health bar selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a heath bar that follows the camera's location but not all the little rotations caused by animations. You may be looking for the child of constraint.

[image]

With these settings as the camera rotates on the x and y axis (like during a run animation) the cube does nothing. However, transform and rotation on the z axis by the camera affect the cube allowing it to always still be in view.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I do this. This is exactly what I want though have no idea how to imply it. I'm new to blender game engine.
Thank you :)

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted a HUD for some animation. I don't know much about the BGE. I do development in Unity